# ID error when inserting row into Acumatica view

Tags: acumatica

I have a row of data (type InventoryItem) that originated from a different Acumatica instance db. I want to simply insert it using the InventoryItemMaint.Item view. I cleared out the originating InventoryID value first since it's an identity column. I tried both nulling it out and setting it to zero. Whatever I set it to, it throws a PXFieldValueProcessingException that the InventoryID can't be found; but of course it's not supposed to be found, it's supposed to be generated when inserted into the db. The code simply does:

```
graph.Item.Insert(row);
```

The error message also mentions the DfltSiteID field. Does it maybe fire all field update events when I call view.Insert() and an event handler might unsafely reference InventoryID? Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: Please post the full exception message. If the item is coming from a different database, then DfltSiteID will likely be invalid.

Comment: Full exception is "An error occurred during processing of the field Default Warehouse value 159 Error: An error occurred during processing of the field Inventory ID value 10043 Error: Inventory ID '10043' cannot be found in the system."

The issue is not DfltSiteID.  It exists in both databases. When setting the DfltSiteID value during insert, it appears to be evaluating InventoryID -- which doesn't exist.  Maybe a DfltSiteID field event is being triggered, which evaluates InventoryID for some reason.  If this is true, can I turn off events when inserting somehow?

Comment: If I null out DfltSiteID before doing the Insert, then the error moves to another field -- Item Class.  And it's still complaining about InventoryID.

Comment: Does the item class exists in the database where you’re trying to insert the item? I suggest trying to insert a blank item and then slowly incorporating the other values from your source item...

Comment: Yes, the DfltSiteID exists in INSite, and the ItemClassID exists in INItemClass.  I'm not sure, but I think the events for these fields are being fired and checking the InventoryID for some reason -- even though this is an insert and it shouldn't be.

Comment: If I null out these values, it just moves on to the next field and errors out looking for that value.  The values exist in the db.  Could it be looking for the values in the cache instead of the db?  Do I have to fill the cache somehow with these reference values - that seems silly.  Can't I just disable validation somehow.  Can't inserts be done without an active row open in the UI?

Comment: @TonyLanzer Could you please add an example of your data and the full code how you are creating the Item object and inserting it?

Comment: The data is simply an InventoryItem object that was persisted in one instance.  I send it to a queue and pick it up with another instance.  Then I create an instance of InventoryItemMaint, and pass the object to the Item view's Insert() method of the graph.

Comment: It seems like what I'm trying to do is just not supported or reliable.  Maybe the only way I can do this is via API, but that's very unfortunate if so.  It couples instances together that are sending/receiving data.  Is there any way to access the data contract that APIs use to transfer data without using the APIs?

Comment: Are you setting your object values null before the first insert? Ex: row.InventoryID = null; then insert the row. You will also need to recalculate all of the ID fields as they could be different, Such as location, warehouse, accounts, etc.

Comment: I nulled out InventoryID which gave an error.  I set it to zero, and also received an error.  All of the row and field events were being fired, though.  If I disable all events, then an ID of zero works. As I said, I think I'm trying to do something that Acumatica can't handle.

Comment: In summary it should work, you just need to change all of your IDs if copying from another instance as they could be different (default warehouse for example).

Comment: Maybe it should, but it doesn't.  IDs are not the issue.  Thanks anyway, but I'm backing up and trying something else because nothing has worked so far.